# Should I call a function within itself

Tags: python

```
def Main():
    print('\nWould you like to:\n1. Create a new account?\n2. Sign in?')
    try:
        Answer = int(input(':'))
    except:
        Answer = 3
    if Answer < 1 or Answer > 2:
        print()
        print('Invalid answer, please try again')
        print()
        Main()
    if Answer == 1:
        NewAccount()
        Main()
```

Is it bad to call the function from within itself as shown above?

As it works I wouldn't even be asking this if it wasn't for the fact that I heard you shouldn't do so from an somewhat unreliable source.

Comment: This is called ["recursion"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)), and it's useful in certain circumstances. This is not one of them. Use a loop.

Comment: In Python you better do not do that. Since Python does not supports tail recursion, you can eventually run out of stack.

Comment: Try wrapping that thing in a while loop.

Comment: Hey guys, where is the fascination with recursion coming from? It seems to me that someone is teaching students to use recursion where loops would be a better fit.

Comment: @quamrana I think a lot of students "discover" recursion when they are trying how to figure out how to prompt a user again while validating inputs. it's interesting to me how many immediately go to recursion.

Comment: It just seems to me that too many are 'discovering' recursion for it to be a coincidence. It took me years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each invocation of a function needs memory on the stack. Python has a recursion limit, to stop too nested function calls.

Another point: loops are more readable and the control flow is clearer:

```
def main():
    while True:
        print('\nWould you like to:\n1. Create a new account?\n2. Sign in?')
        try:
            answer = int(input(':'))
        except ValueError:
            break
        if not 1 <= answer <= 2:
            print()
            print('Invalid answer, please try again')
            print()
        elif Answer == 1:
            new_account()
        else:
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about recursion here. While recursion is not inherently wrong, it can be very tricky with what you are doing and what recursion depth you are at. This would be a more apt way to control the recursion than you currently have.

Also it IS frowned upon to use recursion on your main function and makes it much easier to fall into a recursion trap.

```
def getInput():
    try:
        Answer = int(input(':'))
    except:
        Answer = 3

    if Answer < 1 or Answer > 2:
        print()
        print('Invalid answer, please try again')
        print()
        getInput()

    return Answer

def Main():
    print('\nWould you like to:\n1. Create a new account?\n2. Sign in?')

    Answer = getInput()

    if Answer == 1:
        NewAccount()
```